# Filter displayname for parentheses error

Tags: powershell, properties, filter

My script won't send any information to my .txt file except the headers. I want to find any display names that may contain (), /, _ and so forth. Am I not able to use * symbol to mean that I want any display name filtered that contains a "(" anywhere in the name?

```
#Grab some AD attributes for the specific user ID
$userid = Get-ADUser -filter {displayname -like '*(' -or displayname -like '*_' -or displayname -like '*/'} -SearchBase "OU=Corporate,DC=we,DC=dirsrv,DC=com" -Properties name, displayname, description, manager
```

Trying to make it show up in my txt file but still new to powershell

```
#Grab some AD attributes for the specific user ID
$userids = Get-ADUser -Properties name, displayname, description, manager -filter {displayname -like '*(*' -or displayname -like '*_*' -or displayname -like '*/*'} 

#THIS IS THE FOREACH I'M TRYING TO MAKE WORK
foreach ($userid in $userids)
{
$ID = Get-AdUser ($userid.displayname) -Properties displayname
$userid = $ID.displayname
}

foreach ($userid in $userids)
{
#manager missing
if ($userid.Manager -eq $null) {
    $owner = "MISSING"
    $ownerid = "MISSING"
    $ownername = "MISSING"

} else {
#grab the manager's name, surname, and department
    $owner = Get-ADUser ($userid.Manager) -Properties GivenName, Surname
    $ownerid = $owner.Name
    $ownername = $owner.Surname + "." + $owner.GivenName
   }
}
```

What I'm making so far. Not having good luck tho lol

Comment: working on a foreach loop to grab them currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `-like` operator like you are, you are looking for strings that *end* in (,_, etc. Instead you need to surround the character you are looking for with wildcards:

```
{displayname -like '*(*' -or displayname -like '*_(*' -or displayname -like '*/*'}
```

Alternatively, for a more succinct query, you could use a regular expression:

```
{displayname  -match '[\(\)\\_]'}
```

Note that since (,), and \ are special regular expression characters, you have to escape them with \.

Comment: The `Get-ADUser -filter` argument doesn't support the `-match` operator. Oh how I wish it did, but alas using `-like` is as close as we get.

Comment: I had used 2 * prior but since it wasn't printing I thought I was wrong. Good to know I wasn't. Just won't print still. Trying to figure out how to connect this line with a foreach loop now.

Answer (score 0):

WOW so if I input the code

```
Get-AdUser -Properties displayname -filter {displayname -like '*(*'} | Select displayname
```

Then it will give me all the listings I need of the displayname..... note to self!

Now to connect it with my code :P